# SendKeys CaretSign not sendable

Tags: c#, sendkeys

anyone have experience with the SendKey Methode?

My problem is when I want to send the ^ sign I have read that I had to send it with brackets like this. {^}

But when I do so I get a & Sign?

Do anyone know why? If I make something like {^ 2} I get && but I just wont to get ^ :)

EDIT:
Sorry for the misunderstanding!
FOR ALL MY FIRST COMMENT IS THE WAY I DO IT NOW AND IT WONT WORK LIKE THIS.

---

[image]

Comment: The command is

SendKeys.Send("{^}");

Comment: You should either delete your question or post your own answer and accept it in two days.

Comment: No this isn´t the answer this is how i have tried it and it do not work!

I just want to add the command i currently use. (But as i mentioned it wont work)

Comment: in that case you should have [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18488392/edit) instead of posting a comment.

Comment: @user2139258 Check your keyboard regional settings

Comment: Yes i know now, and i wont do this again. 
(Sorry again for the misunderstanding)

Comment: The Keyboardsettings are German in the running Programm.

Comment: That's very strange, the code is identical (near enough) but the output is different. I just changed my keyboard layout from UK to US and it mine still worked. Have you got another PC handy to try this on - maybe it's something weird in your computer setup.

Comment: I can Setup a virtual machine to test the behaviour.
(about 20minutes)

Comment: On an English keyboard layout, you produce a ^ by pressing Shift+6.  That indeed produces a & on a German keyboard layout.  So for some reason, SendKeys isn't aware that it is supposed to speak German.  Nothing in the question gives a hint why that's the case.

Comment: Got the same behaviour in the virtual machine...
But i have reviewed the MSDN article and I have found a paragraph where the are writing:

**If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.**

So i think it is exactly the Problem...

Comment: I have the same problem with a Swiss German keyboard. Instead of "^" I get a "&".

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}". To specify brace characters, use
>   "{{}" and "{}}". Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys,
>   but you must enclose them in braces.

So the correct syntax for the caret is:

```
SendKeys.Send("{^}");
```

Evidence that it works:
[image]

Comment: As i mentioned above this wont work! The result of this command is a & Sign.

I have read the MSDN article already...

Comment: I tried it before I posted my answer and it worked for me! I'm not sure this is relevant, but have you got your keyboard regional settings correct?